# Visual Studio 2013 does not copy reference assemblies to debug folder

Tags: visual-studio-2013, filenotfoundexception

I'm facing a really stupid issue, don't know which it exactly come from VisualStudio 2013 or not. I describe it as following:

1. I use assembly Sqlite in my Bussiness project (class library)
2. I use Bussiness assembly reference in my WinForm project

But when I build my WinForm, the output debug folder does not contain "Sqlite.dll" then if I run it in another PC, it always show that FileNotFound exception

Do you have any solution for this? Thanks in advanced

Comment: on the references folder in Visual Studio click on the Reference, and then you can set in the Properties window `Copy Local` to true

Comment: I did it with no luck, it only copy that Sqlite.dll to Bussiness debug folder. Not the WinForm debug folder

Comment: could you please elaborate a little bit more how your referencing the projects. Because normally `Copy Local` does exactly what your asking about. Is the Business assembly reference a Solution Reference or have you referenced the DLL from your filebase?

Comment: Sqlite.dll use in Business Project (when build Business, sqlite is copied to Bussiness\Debug folder -> Correct)

Business is add reference to WinForm Project (when Build WinForm, Business.dll is copied to WinForm\Debug folder but the Sqlite.dll is not copied to WinForm\Debug folder...)

Comment: not the sqllite.dll how are you referencing the Business Project in your Winforms project. Over browse or Solution->Projects ?

Comment: Business and WinForm are in the same solution. Only Sqlite assembly is added from the other place

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the referenced DLL in Visual studio Solution Explorer -> Go to Properties and set `Copy Local` to True. That should solve your issue.

Comment: I forgot to tell you that I have done that before posting this and no luck :(

Comment: have you tried copying the dll manually in the bin/debug and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Because of building set to AnyCPU, my environment is x64 so the compiled assemblies are x64. But Sqlite version is x86. So it won't be compiled and outted to debug folder

That is my question, thanks all!!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, your referenced library has set the attribute "Copy Local" to "True".

It might happen, that you need to set this attribute to "False" first and turning it back to "True" after first referencing the assembly. This is caused by it, that the default value for the Attribute is "True" but the copying process works only, if it is indeed set in the project file, which again is done, once the value is set to a non-default one and back.

Or in other words; check your project file, if it contains a tag <Private> inside your tag <ProjectReference>